# Syntax for setting multiple delimiters?

Tags: java, parsing, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I want to set a delimiter so that I get only the words in a java source code.

So punctuation such as (),;=<>*whitespace* etc get ignored.

My goal is to read source code of a java file and detect only the variable names and not the variable types. But punctuation is also part of the variable names sometimes, so I have to block them off.

Ex: public static void main(String[] args){

This line should detect "main" and "args" only and store them away because they are the variable names. But I only need to know how to set the delimiter to ignore the other stuff

So basically, the delimiter should include the following: 
*whitespace*;,()[]{}=<>""

Comment: You are looking to build a parser. Doing so is not in the scope of a question in SO as it is too broad.

Comment: Too broad? How so? All I need is the delimiter to take the characters only by ignoring the other java punctuation involved. I think the delimiter would use around 10 different things. Is 10 too much?

Comment: since you're looking to filter out *words* such as accessors, method return types, object types etc - it means that you cannot do it with a simple string-replace. For example, you want to filter our the word `String`, but you don't want to filter out the variable `myString` or `myStrings` and at the same time you'll also want to filter out `String[]`. And that's only to mention one type with some of the possibilities...

Comment: The goal is to filter out the punctuation in java code + any white spaces.

Comment: "My goal is to read source code of a java file and detect only the variable names and not the variable types." - you have a short memory pal :)

Comment: I did some searching. Please confirm that s.useDelimiter("\\s \\s|\\s(\\s|\\s)\\s"); would set whitespace, (, ) as delimiters

Answer (score 0):

You would also have to handle content in string literals and a whole range of other things. Effectively you will be writing a Java parser.

If you really want to do this, I recommend looking at [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). There are Java grammars available for it, for example [this one](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4).

Answer (score -2):

This can be done in two steps:

```
string values= str.replaceAll("[(),;=<>]","|");  <-- replace all chars with pipe(|)
String[] array = values.split("\\|", -1);
```

Enjoy.

Comment: I'm not sure how.  He's asking how to take multiple delimiters and convert them to a list of words.  The replaceAll() function makes all the delimiters into one, and then split gives him what's left.

Comment: Hey guys, I'm reading in an entire java source code file. So I have to traverse through everything in the source code. So for every string obtained from a .next() method, it needs to consider the words only and determine if they are identifiers or not.

Comment: The question is tagged `java.util.scanner` so it looks like they are asking for a delimiter for Scanner.

Comment: I don't want to replace anything. I want every scanner.next() value to take a string as units without these: ( )[ ]{ } ; , | so I need to know the syntax needed to set each of these as the delimiter in the .useDelimiter() method.